View transitions are glitchy without using deprecated .animation()
I'm trying to comply to the now deprecated .animation(.easInOut), but every time I make adjustments to .animation(_:value:) it breaks the transition.
This code functions how I want with one view sliding into the other, but gives the message that .animation is deprecated
 var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if !showHealthView && !showFuelView && !showTrainView && !showHeartView {
                mainContent
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: transitionDirection))
            }
        
            if showHealthView {
                HealthView(showHealthView: $showHealthView)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading))
            } else if showFuelView {
                FuelView(showFuelView: $showFuelView)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
            } else if showTrainView {
                TrainView(showTrainView: $showTrainView)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
            } else if showHeartView {
                HeartView(showHeartView: $showHeartView)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing))
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }

If I adjust to this code to comply, it breaks the transition and mainContent either doesn't move at all, or starts from the center moves to the side and then back to the center as showHeartView transitions which looks AWFUL.
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if !showHealthView && !showFuelView && !showTrainView && !showHeartView {
            mainContent
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: transitionDirection))
        }
        
        if showHealthView {
            HealthView(showHealthView: $showHealthView)
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading))
        } else if showFuelView {
            FuelView(showFuelView: $showFuelView)
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
        } else if showTrainView {
            TrainView(showTrainView: $showTrainView)
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
        } else if showHeartView {
            HeartView(showHeartView: $showHeartView)
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing))
        }
    }
    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: showHealthView)
    //.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}

Any ideas???

Wherever it is you are updating the flags, try surrounding it with withAnimation. Then you can remove the animation modifier altogether. If you could update the example to make it complete then it might be possible to suggest other alternative solutions too. Currently, the issue is not reproducible without guessing a lot of the implementation.

In the source code, only one of the four toggles is being animated. In the following example, the toggles are replaced with a single enumeration which is then animated.
An enumeration to replace the toggles:
  enum ShowView {
       case health
       case fuel
       case train
       case heart
   }

Simplified code using the enum as the animated value:
  struct ContentView: View {
       @State var showView: ShowView = .train
       
       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               ZStack {
                   switch showView {
                       case .health:
                           HealthView(showHealthView: $showView)
                               .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading))
                       case .fuel:
                           FuelView(showFuelView: $showView)
                               .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
                       case .train:
                           TrainView(showTrainView: $showView)
                               .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
                       case .heart:
                           HeartView(showHeartView: $showView)
                               .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing))
                   }
               }
               .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: showView)

               List { // Added picker to switch views
                   Picker("Show View", selection: $showView) {
                       Text("Health").tag(ShowView.health)
                       Text("Fuel").tag(ShowView.fuel)
                       Text("Train").tag(ShowView.train)
                       Text("Heart").tag(ShowView.heart)
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }


One of the views to transition:
    struct HealthView: View {
        @Binding var showHealthView: ShowView 
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "cross.case.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    
                Text("Health")
            }
        }
    }

Resulting transitions:

Hopefully I didn't over simplify the problem you are having. If I have, please explain in more detail how mainContent should be displayed and transitioned and why it's contained in a ZStack.

I appreciate the simplification as I'm fairly new at this. The goal is to have all of the views centered around mainContent and have the transition work as though it is one image with the view shifting as if it is moving over different parts of the same image if that makes sense. The transitions will only occur between mainContent and the other pages as mainContent is the center of the image.
I'm going to attempt the simplification you recommended and see how it works.
